# Finding a value in XML (from a parameter) PHP

Tags: php, xml, parameters, return

I am looking for a way to find the value of a parameter 'duration' from an XML access

Source :
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/bSCs7NzghSg

I tried something like :

```
        preg_match('#<yt:duration seconds=\'(.*?)\'/>#is',$xml,$resultduration);
    $duration = $resultTitre[count($resultduration)-1];
```

but value return 0

Comment: People are going to tell you that you should not be parsing XML with regex.

Comment: Really ?
Should use simplexml_load_string() ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with SimpleXML. Use the [`children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method for finding the children and [`attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method for accessing the attributes.

Here's a function for that purpose:

```
function getDuration($url) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $duration =  $xml->children('media', true)
                  ->group->children('yt', true)
                    ->duration->attributes('', true)->seconds;
    return $duration; 
}
```

Usage:

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/bSCs7NzghSg';
echo getDuration($url); // => 2461
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1e8gIJ)

Comment: Return : 

Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists

Comment: I changed with :
 $url   = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$videoId;
 $page   = file_get_contents($url);
 $dataBitch  = simplexml_load_string($page);
 echo $dataBitch->title;

Isn t it lighter ?

Comment: @Titus: Lighter in what sense? They do different things. If you're asking about the performance difference between `file_get_contents()` and `simplexml_load_file()` -- then I think `file_get_contents()` would be faster.

Comment: Great informations !
Many many thanks !

echo round( ( getDuration($url) ) /60 );

Answer (score 0):

$file = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/bSCs7NzghSg';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

$result = $xml->xpath('//yt:duration');

foreach ($result as $node) {

```
echo (double) $node['seconds'];
echo ' ';
```

}

Comment: explanation: 1)load the xml file into using simplexml_load_file 2) xpath the xml file using xpath query (//) denotes search globally 3) loop through the nodes 4) get the seconds attribute of that node. 5) cheers ;)